# Displaying chord symbols in music21 with LilyPond?

Tags: python, music21

I'm trying to generate a lead sheet using music21 in Google Colab and lilypond. I have a stream with note objects and chord symbol objects, expecting the chord symbols to be represented as symbols above the notes in the score like a lead sheet, but when I call show('lily.png') on the stream, it realizes the notes of the chord symbol as actual notes, like the following:

[stream with chords represented as notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t832T.png)

I'm entering the chord symbols in the stream with the following:

```
  for chordDur in chords:
    sym = harmony.ChordSymbol(chordDur[0])
    sym.quarterLength = chordDur[1]/4.0
    sym = sym.transpose('P8')
    phrase.insert(currOffset,sym)
    currOffset += chordDur[1]/4.0
```

Where chords is a list of tuples in the form of [chord names, duration in 16th notes], as in ['C', 16'] and 'phrase' is a preexisting stream of notes (the melody in this case). Is this possible / how can this be done?